# An exception occur while Updating/Editing products with a foreign key

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

I am working with .Net Mvc 4, while editing my entries I got this error.

My Error:

> The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_catalog_product_catalog_categories". The conflict occurred in
>   database "DemoE-commerce", table "dbo.catalog_categories", column
>   'id'. The statement has been terminated.

My Edit Controller Code:

```
//EDIT PRODUCT

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult edit_product(catalog_product cat_product)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(cat_product).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("cat_product");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        { throw e; }
        return View();
    }
```

Here are my tables from catalog_categories im getting categories names in catalog product in a dropdownlist

[image]

I need to know how to update data with foreign key table relation, am I missing some piece of code while updating?

need help!!!

Comment: From the error message I'd say the product is assigned to a category that doesn't exist in your database. Can you debug the code and look at the category?

Comment: i have a foreign key realtion with category where my all categories are coming in dropdownlist from the other table to product table but when i select that and press save button it takes me to post controller method where i get error after db.savechanges();

Comment: Check all properties of your object cat_product. Maybe the category is missing.

Answer (score 0):

In you table (`catalog_categories`) design, please right click your foreign key (`FK_catalog_product_catalog_categories`) and select Modify. Set the UPDATE rule on `CASCADE` in Foreign Key relationship dialog under INSERT and UPDATE specifics.

[image]

Or you can do it by:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table
DROP Constraint your_foreign_key
GO

ALTER TABLE your_table
ADD CONSTRAINT [New_FK_Constraint]
FOREIGN KEY (your_column) REFERENCES Referenced_Table(your_column)
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
GO
```

**Based on the update in the question:** It seems like you are trying to update the "id" column in your catalog_categories table, where the record has a connection with products table (id is used as category_id there). Cascade actually should fix such issues, however somehow it did not fix here.. Please make sure you are also updating all the related records in the catalog_products table as well **BEFORE** you change an "id" value in the catalog_categories table like:

```
update catalog_products
set category_id = 5
where category_id = 1

update catalog_categories
set id = 5
where id = 1
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but it's still giving me the same error as above

Comment: Oh, that is surprising, probably we could not find the correct key column. Please do it for the table "dbo.catalog_categories",and the column 'id'. If still not working, please put the table designs in your question.